# Any postgres ORM for Scala with jsonb inherit support

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, orm, jsonb

I have a table customer which has a jsonb type column in PostgreSQL I need a ORM in scala which can declare the class as following

```
 class Customer(val demographics: jsonb,
                val event: string) {
           def this()=this({},"")
    }
```

Is there any inherent support by some ORM like I found Squerl as one but i need to explicitly cast to jsonb

Comment: Have you looked at the [Slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) - PostgreSQL-specific extensions for the [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/)? Its documentation mentions jsonb on [some pages](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/json)

Comment: This seems interesting..thanks but Slick-pg is not a proper ORM it seems...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)  that support jsonb.
Just use jsonb as the type:`<column name="demographics" type="jsonb"/>`

Comment: I think liquibase is a very different kind of tool from the one that the OP is asking for. Does liquibase supports any kind of mapping between DB and code - the essential feature of any [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)?

Comment: I think Liquibase doesn't integrate at code level with Scala ...at least i can't find any ....